# GDI+ Graphics::DrawImage not showing

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, gdi+, gdi

Still working my way through leaning WinAPI and its various libraries, and I'm now trying to figure out GDI+. As a simple test, I'm trying to load an image from a file and draw it to the screen.

Here's the code I'm using (explanation below it):

```
int x=0, y=0;
Image* sprite=Image::FromFile((WCHAR*)"MyImage.png");
Graphics g(dc);
std::cout<<"(x, y)=("<<x<<", "<<y<<")"<<std::endl; // Debug output
std::cout<<"(w, h)=("<<sprite->GetWidth()<<", "<<sprite->GetHeight()<<")"<<std::endl; // Debug output
g.DrawImage(sprite, x, y, (int)sprite->GetWidth(), (int)sprite->GetHeight());
```

So dc is the HDC I'm drawing to, obtained via BeginPaint(). It's definitely fine, because I can draw an ellipse with Ellipse() using that HDC and it shows up fine. I've output the sprite variable's value, and it's a non-null pointer, as it should be.

The weird part is that the output above says the width and height of the image are both 0. What would cause that? I thought maybe the image wasn't being loaded properly, so I tried using both an absolute and a relative path for the FromFile() argument, and nothing changed. I also tried switching from a PNG to a BMP, but no change there, either.

What's going on?

**EDIT** Just tested, and if I load the image as Image* sprite=new Image(L"Path_To_Image"); it works fine. Why doesn't it work with FromFile?

Comment: Your two code samples do completely different things with the strings. Tip for Winapi: Never cast strings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gdiplus expects Unicode strings for methods like `Image::FromFile`.

However in your code you are passing a multibyte string. Simply casting to `WCHAR*` isn't enough to convert a string to Unicode - you need to prefix it with `L` (and you should then remove the cast, which isn't necessary).

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work now. Sort of. In my program, it's drawing the images properly, but it has a massive flicker problem. I'm repainting the window with a thread loop approximately 30 times per second. Currently, I'm clearing it with g.Clear() and then drawing the images shown here. As x and y change, the image moves just fine. But that flicker is ridiculous. Is there a technique for updating the window without flicker?

Comment: Never mind. I finally found it's called "double buffering" and got it to work! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @DanielBurnett, Please try to keep it one question per question in the future.

Comment: Gdiplus is slow. Double-buffering by painting to a memory DC and then blitting to the display is the usual solution, although 30 fps is probably too fast even for raw GDI to keep up with. You may want to investigate Direct2D.